# PHP - Normalize user input array

Tags: php, arrays, string

If have an array like this:

```
array
  0 => string '62 52, 53' (length=9)
  1 => string '54' (length=2)
```

It's from user input, and you never know how/what they enter ;)

What I want in the end is this:

```
array
  0 => string '62' (length=2)
  1 => string '52' (length=2)
  2 => string '53' (length=2)
  3 => string '54' (length=2)
```

Here's how I do it:

```
  $string = implode(',', $array);
  $string = str_replace(', ', ',', $string);
  $string = str_replace(' ', ',', $string);
  $array = explode(',', $string);
```

Seems really clunky. Is there a more elegant way? One that maybe has better performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On each string:

```
preg_match_all("/[ ,]*(\d+)[ ,]*/", $list, $matches);
```

Then read `$matches[1]` for the numbers

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about performance but you can use a regex to grab only numbers after you join everything into a string.

```
$string = implode(' ', $array);
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use **preg_split** and **array_merge** (PHP 4, PHP 5)